# Class which can allow to create Only 'n' number of Objects

Tags: java

This question is similar to singleton, but i need to create a class that can allow 'n' number of objects only, Below is my code

```
  public class MSInt {

    private static MSInt instance = null;

    private static int count = 0;

    private MSInt()
    {

    }


    public static MSInt getInstance()
    {
        if(count < 5){
            instance = new MSInt();
             count++;
             return instance;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

This is working but i am thinking a better solution than this if any.

Comment: Your solution is appropriate, given the requirement. You'll have to keep track of the number of classes somehow, obviously. A static counter as a class variable is logical.

Comment: If you are working in multi threaded environment use synchronization.

Comment: Seems good to me. Although you might want to change the signature to `public synchronized static MSInt getInstance()` to avoid race condition.

Comment: Might be worth including a thrown exception for when there are too many instances so you can have custom behavior for if there are too many. Will post an answer.

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion about what was best in your situation? If your issue is resolved, don't forget to upvote and accept an answer. If none of the current answers help, it's perfectly acceptable to post your own answer and select that one as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a much cleaner way of doing it. You wouldn't need any counters.
Also it looks nice.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MSInt {

    private static int MAX_OBJS = 10;

    private static ArrayList<MSInt> instances = new ArrayList<MSInt>(MAX_OBJS);

    private MSInt() {}

    public static MSInt mkInstance() {
        if(instances.size() < MAX_OBJS){
            MSInt obj = new MSInt();
            instances.add(obj);
            return obj;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<MSInt> getInstances() {
        return instances;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the use of an extra ArrayList here..??

Comment: "You wouldn't need any counters", but isn't the MAX_OBJS exactly the same?

Comment: Are you not planning on using the instances at all from inside the class?

Comment: @ChandraMohan It's not counting is it? :P

Comment: +1, a collection/array is important because otherwise one of your objects might have been removed with garbage collection and the static count will not have gone down to reflect the change. I would personally prefer an array though because you can define the max in the array rather than as a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is :

```
        private static MSInt instance = null;
```

this is overwrite methods;
use like this Array :

```
       private static MSInt[] instance = null;
```

and use a for loop:

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
        instance[i] = new MSInt();
        return instance[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a decorator pattern

so create a class `LimitedList<T> extends AbstractList<T>` and override `add` methods in order to check if size is exceeded

I've put code [here (gist)](https://gist.github.com/bsorrentino/445c0f03e48c95b46604)

Answer (score 0):

Using an array or collection means that garbage collection won't remove any of your instances without your knowledge, and it means you can retrieve instances later if required. Using an an `MSInt[]` might be most practical because it is already capable of making sure only a certain number of objects exist in it. The `getInstance()` method then loops through the array and if it finds an empty slot, creates a new instances, puts it in the empty spot and returns the result.

```
public class MSInt {

    private static MSInt[] instances = new MSInt[10];

    private MSInt(){ }

    public synchronized static MSInt getInstance() /*throws TooManyException*/{          
        for(int i = 0 ; i<instances.length() ; i++){
             if(instances[i]==null){
                 MSInt ms = new MSInt();
                 instances[i] = ms;
                 return ms;  
             }
        }
        // throw new TooManyException("There are already 10 instances of MSInt");
        return null;          
    }
}
```

Some exception handling might also be useful. You could throw a custom exception to show that too many instances already exist. Which would make it much more manageable later because you can then define more robust custom behavior for if the array is already full. By removing the comments in the class above and creating the below class, that should work nicely.

```
public class TooManyException extends Exception {

  public TooManyException(String message){
     super(message);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. replace `public static MSInt getInstance()` to `public static MSInt getInstance(int number)`. That way you will be able to specify every time what object you are going to get.
2. Define difference between instances. What attributes does your instances possess? In your example all objects looks the same - it becomes unclear why do you need more than one of them.
3. Think about initialization. Do you need lazy initialization, or can you initialize all the instances in class initialization. Then you can declare them `public static final` and deny defining `getInstance()`

BTW, `enum` is class that has exactly n instances (by design). It's very likely that defining `MSInt` as `enum` will be the most convenient for you.